# How to remove empty node in JsonNode

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

i have some json, like this:

```
String str = "{\"menu\":[{\"form1\":\"nameForm1\"}, {\"form2\":\"nameForm2\"}]}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode testNode = objectMapper.readTree(str);
```

After some actions, I modified my json. for example

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldIterator = testNode.fields();
while (fieldIterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fieldIterator.next();
    if (entry.getValue().isArray()){
        for (JsonNode arrayNode : entry.getValue()){
            if (arrayNode.path("form2").isMissingNode()) {
                ((ObjectNode) arrayNode).removeAll();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

And my json began to look like:

```
{"menu":[{},{"form2":"nameForm2"}]}
```

How can I get json without empty array elements, i.e.

```
{"menu":[{"form2":"nameForm2"}]}
```

Comment: There are tons of JSON libraries out there. Which one do you use?

Comment: You need to remove arrayNode from entry, currently you are just removing arrayNode's properties

Comment: i use com.fasterxml.jackson

Comment: Ömer Erden, can you show example. please. what do you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed in comment you need to remove arrayNode variable(which must be named as arrayElementNode ) from arrayNode(which is entry.getValue()), currently you are just removing arrayNode's(arrayElementNode's) properties

Here is the code with this logic

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldIterator = testNode.
while (fieldIterator.hasNext()) 
{
   Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fieldIterator.next();
   if (entry.getValue().isArray())
   {
      ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) entry.getValue();
      for(int i = arrayNode.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
      {
         if(arrayNode.get(i).path("form2").isMissingNode())
            arrayNode.remove(i);

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: ok. thank you. but if i want to remove 2 elements. The cycle did one itertion.